# Unable to Bind a combobox selected item to a TextBox when combobox itself is a part of a datagrid column

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, combobox

**I want bind the subject name in a textbox when the selected index is changed in comboxbox which i am using within a DataGrid**

*Here is my code*
  ////

```
   <Window x:Class="WpfGridDemo.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:Students="clr-namespace:WpfGridDemo"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">


<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBox Height="22" Width="113" Text="{Binding ElementName=ComboSubjects,Path= SelectedItem.Subject}"/>

    <DataGrid x:Name="ComboSubjects" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" Grid.Row="1" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding StudentDetailsList, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn  Binding="{Binding Name }" Header="Student Name" Width="200" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Subjects" Width="100">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Subject}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>

                        <ComboBox Name="ComboSubjects" SelectedValuePath="SubjectNames" 
             SelectedValue="{Binding Subject}" 
             DisplayMemberPath="SubjectNames" 
             ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.SubjectList,Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" />

                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>

</Grid>
</Window>
```

/////

```
 using System;
 using System.Windows;
 using System.Windows.Data;

 namespace WpfGridDemo
 {
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
 {
     public MainWindow()
     {
         InitializeComponent();
         StudentDetails studentDetailsList = new StudentDetails();
         this.DataContext = studentDetailsList;
     }
 }
 }
```

///

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace WpfGridDemo
{
public class StudentDetails
{

    public ObservableCollection<Subjects> SubjectList
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<StudentModel> StudentDetailsList
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public StudentDetails()
    {
        StudentDetailsList = new ObservableCollection<StudentModel>();
        StudentDetailsList.Add(new StudentModel() { Name = "Rohit", Subject = "Java" });
        StudentDetailsList.Add(new StudentModel() { Name = "Tarun", Subject = "C#" });

        SubjectList = new ObservableCollection<Subjects>();
        SubjectList.Add(new Subjects() { SubjectNames = "Java" });
        SubjectList.Add(new Subjects() { SubjectNames = "C#" });
        SubjectList.Add(new Subjects() { SubjectNames = "Python" });
        SubjectList.Add(new Subjects() { SubjectNames = "Rails" });
    }
 }
}
```

//

```
  using System.ComponentModel;
  namespace WpfGridDemo
   {
   public class StudentModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
    private string subject;
    public string Subject
    {
        get
        {
            return this.subject;
        }
        set
        {
            this.subject = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("Subject");
        }
    }

    public string Name
    { get; set; }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

}

public class Subjects : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _subjectNames;
    public string SubjectNames
    {
        get
        {
            return this._subjectNames;
        }
        set
        {
            this._subjectNames = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("SubjectNames");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
   }
 }
```

**Please Provide any solution to bind the items of the combobox to the texbox when the selection is changed.**

Answer (score 0):

you can achive this by setting **IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"** on DataGrid

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="GridWithComboBox" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" .....
```

and needs to change your ComboBox Binding to ...

```
SelectedValue="{Binding Subject,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

Comment: IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"  is not working with the current code . do i need to change the text box binding as well?

Comment: Use SelectedItem instead of SelectedValue in your binding of TextBox

Comment: still i am getting the same output as before. when i change the subject name in combobox it is not updating my textbox value.

Comment: when you change combo selection is it affecting another cell?

Comment: implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface on StudentModel, binding works only when PropertyChanged event fires

Comment: no change in other cells at that particular time when i change the combobox values.

Comment: strange! also not updating another gridview column ?

Comment: try with removing binding mode=OneWay

Comment: still it dosent work. i think it is because of using the combobox inside the datagrid so the textbox binding is not recognizing the selected item change of the combobox.

Comment: it should work, there must be some small mistake, try putting breakpoint on Subject property's setter and check is it coming there or update your latest code in question.

Comment: yes it is not coming to the setter of Subject property.

Comment: yes i got it, its bcos when you change row than the edit is getting commited, you change your ComboBox bindig SelectedValue="{Binding Subject,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"